# The scene becomes dark when reloaded

Tags: unity, lighting

I have a prototype of a simple game. When I hit a spike, the game restarts, but when it does the whole scene becomes dark. The light intensity level stays the same.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

Comment: Does this occur in a built executable, or only in the editor? I observed something similar recently, but thankfully it only affected in-editor testing and was not a problem in the released game.

Comment: I dont know is there a way to check it

Comment: Build your game, run it, and observe whet happens when you hit a spike.